Range of the function $ f(x) = \frac{1}{1 - 2 \cos(x)}$
My textbook has this question:

Range of  $ f(x) = \frac{1}{1 - 2 \cos(x)}$  is:
(A) $ [ \frac{1}{3}, 1]$
(B) $ [ -1, \frac{1}{3}]$
(C) $ (-∞, -1] \cup [\frac{1}{3}, ∞] $
(D) $ [\frac{-1}{3}, 1] $

To solve this, I first did:
$$ -1 \leq \cos(x) \leq 1 $$
Ultimately, I wrote:
$$ -1 \leq 1 - 2 \cos(x) \leq 3 $$
After that shouldn't it become the following?
$$ \frac{1}{3} \leq \frac{1}{1 - 2 \cos(x)} $$
and
$$ \frac{1}{1 - 2 \cos(x)} \leq -1 $$
This would make option (C) correct, but my textbook says option (B). Why?

Option (C) looks correct.  Perhaps your textbook has a typo.

Is it possible that the textbook asks for the complement of the range or something along those lines, and perhaps that the closed [,] brackets in option B are actually meant to be open (,) brackets and that there's a missing minus sign? A quick look at the graph of the function as it's written confirms that (C) is incorrect as the problem currently stands. (It's also likely the textbook just has a typo—just trying to cover all the bases though!)

Can I ask also why options (B) and (D) are identical? Are they meant to be?

@Kyle no I made a minor typo there. Changing it now. Thanks for pointing it out.

@Kyle To answer your first question, no. I think it may be just a typo in my textbook.

With that adjustment, it really looks like they either meant to ask for the complement of the range and also didn't use the correct type of brackets, or they just made a typo. My guess is that it was a typo :)

None of the answers are correct. Your math is. You can approach the problem "backwards".
$\exists c| f(c)=2 \implies $ A,B, and D are false.
$\frac{1}{1-2\cos (c)}=2\implies 1/2=1-2\cos (c)\implies \cos c=1/4\implies c = \arccos(1/4)$
C doesn't work because of the ] bracket used with $+\infty$. It would be correct if it was ).
